# How can I increase the resolution of Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS in VMware Workstation Pro 15?

Tags: windows, resolution, vmware, kubuntu

Environment:

- Hypervisor: VMWare Workstation Pro 15.0.0
- Host: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- Guest: Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. VMware extension pack installed, guest was installed via VMware EasyInstall.

How can I increase the resolution of Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS in VMware Workstation Pro 15?

Changing the resolution in Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS doesn't work:

[image: ku]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is caused by a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407058) in [`kscreen`](https://github.com/KDE/kscreen) with Kubuntu 20.04. The fix is to disable `kscreen` by executing in the terminal ("Konsole") ([command source](https://redd.it/g8bkkz)):

```
qdbus org.kde.kded5 /kded unloadModule kscreen
```

Alternatively, and for a more durable result, one may disable the `kscreen` service as follows:

[image]

The bug is absent from Kubuntu 18.04, Kubuntu 22.04, and Ubuntu.

Comment: Excellent self-answered question!

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, using Kubuntu 20.04 directly. That distribution worked only on Intel GPU. with an Nvidia GPU the screen remained black. Later the bug has been resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).